# C# Foreach-loop giving Null-error

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, null

I'm writing a bit of code, and there is a part that gives me hassles.
I'm having the following structure in my code:

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
    try
    {
        bool n = node.previous == null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("error.txt");
            s.WriteLine(e.Message);
            s.WriteLine("-----------");
            s.Close();
        }
}
```

In here Node is a custom type, the node.prev variable is also a custom type (Location). Running this gives the following error-log:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
-----------
```

I'm 100% sure that node isn't null (*which should be made impossible by foreach* = Not true, sorry!). Also, as you can see in the following listing, the Node.previous is set to null at declaration:

```
public class Node
{
    public Location previous = null;
    public Location location;
    public int distance;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have no idea how I can fix these exeptions occuring, and  I'm kind of at the end of having any ideas on how to solve this. Can anybody help me with this?

Note that these are all not the final code, but I sifted the parts that didn't matter!

Thanks in advance,
Delpee

**EDIT: Ricovox helped me to the solution with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939917/1764970), thanks a lot!**

Comment: 1) Which line is throwing the exception? 2) If you don't know where the error is happening how do you know the rest of the code doesn't matter?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on that line of code? What are the values?  Is nodes null?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in your foreach line and see whether my nodes has members or not! you can trace what is happening using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("current node:"+ node.Location.ToString()+...);

Comment: I can't put a breakpoint, because this is for Google's AI challenge, which has a weird system making it impossible to debug the classical way. I know this is the problem because this is where the exception is caught.

Comment: You can write to the output window with [tracepoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=vs.100).aspx) without having to update your code.

Comment: _"I'm 100% sure that node isn't null (which should be made impossible by foreach)."_ As others have said, most likely, `node` is null. The statement that you made leads me to believe you have a misconception on what `foreach` actually does

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what Foreach does (and I'm still 100% sure it will not be null). This fixed it: bool n = Nullable.Equals(null,node.prev);

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved your issue, but your wording made is sound as if using a foreach loop prevented the resulting items from being null. That probably sent up red flags to a lot of people that node was null, since your explanation for why it is not didn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, reading back it does! I actually checked it for being null, was what made me so sure. I'll try to construct my phrases more careful next time! Thanks for the effort anyway!

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm posting another answer in response to your comment:

> "I have checked for node being null, it isn't, at any point."

If that IS true, there here are some other options;

1. Take a look at the `node.previous` class/struct definition. It COULD implement a CUSTOM `==` operator that throws an error when compared to null. As an example, think about the `Nullable<T>` type. It has an overloaded `==` operator that returns true if the HasValue property is false (obviously, since it is a struct it isn't truly null, but overloading the operator gives the desired behavior.) To fix this, you could test `object.ReferenceEquals(node.previous, null)` which wouldn't be overloaded. If you have access to change the `node.previous` definition, perhaps you can find out why the overloaded operator throws an exception when compared to null (which it obviously shouldn't)
2. `nodes` could be null, in which case it is the foreach statement that is throwing the error. Test `nodes == null` before the foreach.

**---------------Edit---------------**

As [Jeppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) pointed out, my analogy with `Nullable<T>` (in option #1, above) could be misleading (in fact it did confuse the discussion, although the point itself was correct). In order to better illustrate the idea of overriding the `==` operator, I've posted an example below that demonstrates the `Container` type. This type is a struct, so it can never be null itself, but it contains a single Value object.
(The point of this struct is that you can work with any `Container` object without worrying whether or not it is null, even though the contained `Value` object might be null). The main thing to note is that when a Container is compared with `==` to null, the result will be true if `Value` is `null`, which would NOT be true if the `==` operator weren't overridden (because a struct can never be null).

```
public struct Container {
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsNull { get { return Value == null; } }
    public static bool operator ==(Container x, object y) { return x.Equals(y); }
    public static bool operator !=(Container x, object y) { return !x.Equals(y); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj is Container)
            return Value == ((Container)obj).Value;
        return Value == obj;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode(); }
}

////---------Test----------
var x = new Container { Value = null };
var y = new Container { Value = "hi" };
var z = new Container { Value = null };
Print(x == null); //true 
Print(x == y);    //false
Print(x == z);    //true
```

And just in case you are wondering how overriding `==` would affect a class, I've written another example below that demonstrates a `Box` class. It's similar to the `Container` struct, except that we have to deal with the case in which the Box object is null itself. Note that in this case, there is another surprising result of overriding `==`. Two reference types can be  equal (`==`) to each other, even if they reference different objects, as long as they have equal `Value` properties.

```
public class Box {
    public static bool ItemsEqual(object x, object y) {
        object xval, yval;
        xval = x is Box ? (x as Box).Value : x;
        yval = y is Box ? (y as Box).Value : y;
        return xval == yval;
    }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsNull { get { return Value == null; } }
    public static bool operator ==(Box x, object y) { return ItemsEqual(x, y); }
    public static bool operator !=(Box x, object y) { return !ItemsEqual(x, y); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return ItemsEqual(this, obj); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return Value == null ? 0 : Value.GetHashCode(); }
}

////---------Test----------
object n = null;
Box w = null;
Box x = new Box { Value = null };
Box y = new Box { Value = "hi" };
Box z = new Box { Value = "hi" };

Print(w == null);  //true (uses overridden '==' because w is defined as a Box)
Print(w == n);     //true
Print(x == w);     //true 
Print(x == null);  //true 
Print(x == n);     //true 

Print(w == y);    //false
Print(x == y);    //false
Print(y == z);    //true (actual ref's differ, but values are ==)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it: bool n = Nullable.Equals(null,node.prev);

Comment: Was `node.prev` actually a nullable type? You could have just gotten lucky because maybe the overloaded operator had an error, but the `Equals` override didn't.

Comment: Node.Prev is nullable, yes, but it's type (Location) had a custom '==' operator, which couldn't handle null (not my code! :P), which caused the problem.

Comment: I think you mean that the `Location` type is "nullable" in the sense that it can set to null, but it isn't actually a `Nullable<T>`, right? Unless google uses alternate versions of the framework dlls, `Nullable<T>` is a struct which cannot be inherited. So there is no way `Location` could be a true `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Since `Location` is NOT a `Nullable<T>`, I would avoid using `Nullable.Equals`.  Instead use `object.Equals` to compare `Node.Prev` with null. If `Node.Prev` is a class (NOT a ValueType) it would be even better to use `ReferenceEquals(Node.Prev, null)` just in case `Location.Equals(object x)` method is overridden.
I haven't checked, but my assumption is that `Nullable.Equals` will call object.Equals in the event that neither argument is a `Nullable<T>`. So your code probably WILL work fine, but a more correct answer would not use Nullable to compare objects that are not `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: No, I don't think location is a Nullable<T>, but as it is a custom class, I should be able to set a value of type Location to null, shouldn't I? I will try ReferenceEquals instead ;).

Comment: @Delpee OK, so `Location` was a **class** overloading the `==` operator in an incorrect way? Can you please show the `class` declaration for `Location` including the `==` operator? You must fix the wrong implementation of `==`. Saying `Nullable.Equals(null, node.previous)` is meaningless! It will actually call `object.Equals` because the overload defined in the `Nullable` static class does not apply. So it ends up calling the override of the virtual `object.Equals(object)` which I really hope your `Location` class has. So use `ReferenceEquals`, or use `(object)(node.previous) == (object)null`.

Comment: ricovox: It is possible to misunderstand your analogy with the `Nullable<T>` struct. It is not a perfect analogy because: **(1)** the [`Nullable<T>` struct (see for yourself)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) does not actually (in the .NET Framework itself) overload the `==` operator. This "overload" is the **lifted operator** defined in the C# Language Specification, and the compiler creates the required logic (checking `HasValue` and so on). And **(2)** if you really had to compare two `Nullable<T>`, it would be catastrophic to use `ReferenceEquals` because of boxing.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely problem is that `node` **is** null!. There is nothing about the foreach statement that would prevent `node` from being null, because in general an IEnumerable object (e.g. a list or collection) **CAN** contain null as a valid item.

No error would be thrown if `previous` is null (unless the `node.prev` class/struct overrides the `==` operator).

As others have mentioned, put in a test like this to verify:

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
    bool n;
    try
    {
        if (node == null) 
        {
           n = true; //do something to deal with a null node
        }
        else 
        {
          n = node.previous == null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("error.txt");
        s.WriteLine(e.Message);
        s.WriteLine("-----------");
        s.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the most unexperienced programmer, I've checked for node being null, it isn't in any case (that's why I was so sure). Fixed it thanks to ricovox: bool n = Nullable.Equals(null,node.prev);

Comment: Sorry for assuming you were a newbie :-)  If you had mentioned the google challenge and that you had already verified that node wasn't ever null, that would have put your question in a different perspective :-)   As it turns out, it seems like this was a pretty good test google used, because people don't often consider operator overrides, and they CERTAINLY don't expect those overrides to throw exceptions for common comparisons like `(x==null)`. So it's definitely understandable that this error would cause some confusion! Good luck with the rest of the challenge!!

Answer (score 1):

If `nodes` were `null` the exception would occur *before* the loop, and the exception wouldn't be caught.

Since the `previous` member is a simple field, the only possibility I see is that one of the `node` members of your `nodes` collection is `null`. You can do this:

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
  if (node == null)
    throw new Exception("I told you so");
}
```

---

**EDIT:** OK, it turned out there was one possibility I didn't see, and that was a broken overload of the `==` operator. To make sure you call the usual overload, say:

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
  bool n = (object)(node.previous) == (object)null;
}
```

(actually it will suffice to cast just one side of the `==` operator to `object`), or equivalently use [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx):

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
  bool n = object.ReferenceEquals(node.previous, null);
}
```

But you **must** fix the wrong implementation of the `==` overload.

If you had posted the stack trace of the exception in your original question, it would have been clear to most users here on SO that the exception came from a call to your `==` overload. So next time, inspect your stack trace.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that the try/catch block wasn't surrounding the `foreach` loop. Edited out of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that ensures that `node` is not null, since `Node` is not a value type. Mind giving more details?

Answer (score 0):

set a breakpoint at your line that starts with `bool` and verify that node is not null and that nodes is not null.  My guess is that either nodes is null, or else it contains a null value if it's not a type-safe list.

Comment: That is not possible, as I don't have any debugging options (sorry for mentioning). This is for the AI challenge (Google), which uses a weird system which makes debugging impossible! I have checked for node being null, it isn't, at any point. Node.prevs could be null, but that shouldn't be a problem when comparing it with null, would it?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm 100% sure that node isn't null

But I'm 100% sure that an element in *nodes* is null! try this:

```
foreach (Node node in nodes)
{
    try
    {
        if(null == node) throw new Exception("This is not expected!");
        bool n = node.previous == null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            if(File.Exists("error.txt")) File.Delete("error.txt");
            using(StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("error.txt")){
            s.WriteLine(e.Message);
            s.WriteLine("-----------");
            s.Close();}
        }
}
```

Comment: Following code doesn't create an error message:                  bool n = node == null;
if (n)
{
    StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("error.txt");
    s.WriteLine("n == null");
    s.Close();
}

Comment: @user1764970, so maybe the message is in file from before; truncate the error log file for each run please...I edited the answer to do this.

Comment: I checked it for being null, it isn't ever (I've been programming for some time, believe me, it will not be null). It's fixed, turned out that Location had a custom '==' operator, which aparently didn't handle null very good, fixed it using the following: bool n = Nullable.Equals(null,node.prev);